# android Illegal state exception at end of activity

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I have an activity which starts another activity (it's child) upon a button click. This activity accepts some values from text fields and inserts it into a database. Somehwere there is an error and the activity closes saying "Unfortunately, app has closed", but all the values ARE entered into the DB. I have no idea what's going on, please help me. Here is the debug:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
View$1.onClick(View) line: 3599 
Button(View).performClick() line: 4204  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 17355 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: post your code and indicate which line throws the exception

Comment: You actually have to click the end session button to see the application stack trace.

Comment: Have you actually given this a thought? How are people supposed to help you if you just say "it crashes". Provide code or something else please, otherwise nobody will have a magic solution…

Answer (score 0):

Post your code and mention line number. you can get infected line number in LOGCAT. check your Manifest xml file  entries.